# How can I add an IP range to the SMTP relay service?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

We continually add and remove IP's of servers that use the SMTP relay service and we do it manually, in the admin console.
We've looked at the documentation, and we don't see any reference to setting these rules in the API.
Is this possible to do?

Edit.- To do this in the console, you can folllow the procedure that is described in support.google.com/a/answer/2956491 (first step, point 8). –
I haven't found any command to do it in the Admin SDK API. I don't know if there will be something else.

Comment: Hi, can you provide the documentation referencing how to do this in the console, in order to clarify what's the feature you mentioned?

Comment: First, you mention an API. What API? Can you link documentation? Also, adding your current command may make this question much more likely to be answered.

Comment: To do this in the console, you can folllow the procedure that is described in https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491 (first step, point 8).

Comment: I haven't found any command to do it in the Admin SDK API.
I don't know if there will be something else.

Comment: Hi, have you checked [this](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings#managing_email_gateway_and_routing)?